# C# Textbox to Save Data on XML

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFilename = "Student_" + Tools.IDStudent + ".xml";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string[] split = txtName.Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
    string[] split2 =txtAddress.Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

    foreach (string s in split)
        foreach (string s2 in split2)
        {
            if (s != "")
                if (s2 != "")
                {
                    string str = s;
                    string str2 = str.Replace("&", "&amp");
                    string strx = s2;
                    string str3 = strx.Replace("&", "&amp");

                    if (File.Exists(strFilename))
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
                        XmlElement elmXML = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Student");
                        string strNewPending = "<Name>" + str2 + "</Name>"+
                                              "<Address>" + str3 + "</Address>";
                        elmXML.InnerXml = strNewPending;
                        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elmXML);
                        xmlDoc.Save(strFilename);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if file is not found, create a new xml file*/
                        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strFilename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(strFilename);
                        xmlWriter.Close();
                        xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
                        XmlNode Clients = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                        XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Student");
                        XmlElement childNode2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                        XmlElement childNode3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Address");

                        XmlText Namex = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Name");
                        XmlText Addressx = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Address");

                        Namex.Value = str2;
                        Addressx.Value = str3;
                        Clients.AppendChild(childNode);
                        childNode.AppendChild(childNode2);
                        childNode.AppendChild(childNode3);
                        childNode2.AppendChild(Namex);
                        childNode3.AppendChild(Addressx);
                        xmlDoc.Save(strFilename);
                     }
                 }
     }
 }
```

i have two textboxes (txtName.text and txtAddress.text)

in txtName.text when i input

- Tom and Jerry
- Mickey Mouse

in txtAddress.text when i input

- Cartoon Network
- Anime

the code above displays

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Student_1.xml>
   <Student>
         <Name>Tom and Jerry</Name>
         <Address>Cartoon Network</Address>
   </Student>
   <Student>
         <Name>Tom and Jerry</Name>
         <Status>Anime</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
         <Name>Mickey Mouse</Name>
         <Address>Cartoon Network</Address>
    </Student>
    <Student>
         <Name>Mickey Mouse</Name>
         <Address>Anime</Address>
    </Student>
    </Student_1.xml>
```

**how would i modify my code to display this output only**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Student_1.xml>
   <Student>
         <Name>Tom and Jerry</Name>
         <Address>Cartoon Network</Address>
   </Student>
   <Student>
         <Name>Mickey Mouse</Name>
         <Status>Anime</Status>
</Student>
</Student_1.xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nested `foreach` loop. Instead, use single `for` loop to access items at the same index from both collection (`split` and `split2`) :

```
//set maxIndex to length of the longest array
var maxIndex = (split.Length > split2.Length) ? split.Length : split2.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
{
    //get item in index i from array split 
    var s = (split.Length>i) ? split[i] : "";
    //get item in index i from array split2 
    var s2 = (split2.Length>i) ? split2[i] : "";

    //the rest of code below remain untouched
    if (s != "")
        if (s2 != "")
        {
            string str = s;
            string str2 = str.Replace("&", "&amp");
            string strx = s2;
            string str3 = strx.Replace("&", "&amp");

            if (File.Exists(strFilename))
            {
                xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
                XmlElement elmXML = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Student");
                string strNewPending = "<Name>" + str2 + "</Name>" +
                                      "<Address>" + str3 + "</Address>";
                elmXML.InnerXml = strNewPending;
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elmXML);
                xmlDoc.Save(strFilename);
            }
            else
            {
                //if file is not found, create a new xml file*/
                XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strFilename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                xmlWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
                xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(strFilename);
                xmlWriter.Close();
                xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
                XmlNode Clients = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Student");
                XmlElement childNode2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                XmlElement childNode3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Address");

                XmlText Namex = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Name");
                XmlText Addressx = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Address");

                Namex.Value = str2;
                Addressx.Value = str3;
                Clients.AppendChild(childNode);
                childNode.AppendChild(childNode2);
                childNode.AppendChild(childNode3);
                childNode2.AppendChild(Namex);
                childNode3.AppendChild(Addressx);
                xmlDoc.Save(strFilename);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: how about if it has 3 textboxes sir??? what should be the code look like (txtName.text,txtAddress.text,txtContactNumber.text)???

Comment: seems it works flawlessly even if i will add the third textbox :D